# Android SQLite database to a server

Tags: android, sqlite, google-app-engine

I have an Android application which stores user's data in a SQLite database (containing 4 tables). Each table has an Integer Primary Key (Auto-incremented).

To get an idea of the scale:

3 of those tables have less than 7 fields and aren't expected to have more than 10 entries. 
1 table having 8 fields, gets roughly 5 entries **per day** on an average.

What I want is the database to be synced to cloud - for many reasons, including

1. The data to be in sync across all of user's devices
2. To collect anonymous data, for research purposes, if the user has opted in.

I realize I would require a multi-tenant database. I want to know an efficient way to do this.

If I use a MySQL database on a web server, would this be efficient? How do I approach multi-tenancy in this case?

Or, do I need  to use a cloud service like Google App Engine? (Which is completely new to me)

Comment: maybe you can use cloud database api like [netmera](http://www.netmera.com/) api

Comment: Do you want to send data directly to database or you could create a webservice for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should consider using GAE and its datastore.  It also supports SQL, but I think your application is well suited to the datastore.

Your datastore would have 5 'kinds' (these are like tables) - the four you listed above and a User kind.  Your four kinds would have a key path that would group them beneath their respective user.  This would take care of the multi-tenancy and it would be very efficient: retrieving and writing these groups (defined by the key path hierarchy) is efficient and cheap.

For a quick intro to these concepts of the datastore I recommend [this page](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts) of the objectify docs.

GAE supports Java, so not only can you use the same language on client and server, but you can also share code.  It requires a bit of care when organizing your code (and watch out for logging) but this has considerable benefits particularly if Android is your only client.